# How do I redirect from a built-in bin to execute an AppImage instead?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardlink, kate, appimage

Scenario: the current version of Kate in Ubuntu 18LTS points at their customized version (which doesn't appear to support regex search capability). The bin is: `/usr/bin/kate`.

Desired solution: run the Kate AppImage (which has the regex search/replace functionality).  The AppImage currently resides in `~/Downloads`.

Question: how do I redirect the system to execute the AppImage version of Kate, instead of the built-in version?

Can I simply create a link to the AppImage in `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it appears you can...  i.e. in my case I replaced the existing kate bin with a link that points to the appimage:

```
# 1st remove the existing kate binary
# (cp kate somewhere first if you want to keep a copy)
sudo rm /usr/bin/kate

# 2nd create a link in the system bin that points to the appimage
sudo link [directory where the appimage resides]/Kate.AppImage /usr/bin/kate
```

Done!  The system will now execute the appimage when 'kate' is executed (e.g. via context menus).

=========================

## UPDATE...

The above solution kinda works... it does run the appimage, however the parameters normally passed to kate (i.e. file to open) are lost in the hard link.

So...  the *better* solution is to create a simple executable shell script (named 'kate' in the /usr/bin directory) to execute the appimage:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec [directory where the appimage resides]/Kate.AppImage "$@"
```

This passes any provided parms to the appimage.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep (for whatever reasons) your system-installed Kate in *`/usr/bin/kate`*...

Then do not touch it. Instead create a directory in your `$HOME` named `bin` (it may already be present depending on the Linux distro you run).

Inside that directory, create a symlink:

```
ln -sf ~/Downloads/kate.AppImage ~/bin/kate
```

This may already work. If not, you have to move the `~/bin` directory to the front of your path:

```
export PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}  # if you use Bash
```

To permanently modify this `$PATH`, add this same line into `${HOME}/.bashrc`